# Saving data form in django without editable property for admin-django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to save the data of a form that user submit.
But I don't wanna the admin be able to edit those data at all.
I tried the readonly_field stuffs, but that didn't work.

my models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):

first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
country = CountryField()
```

my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User)

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
          readonly_fields=('first_name', 'country')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add class `MyAdmin` also into the User  for that to work .

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User
    class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
              readonly_fields=('first_name', 'country')
    admin.site.register(User,MyAdmin)
```